# Help to clarify probability confusion regarding Bonferroni Inequality

Tags: probability, probability-theory

So I know that the Bonferroni inequality states this formula:
$$ P (A_1 \cap A_2) >= P(A_1) + P(A_2) -1$$

In the lecture, the instructor describes the explanation for this as:
$$ P ((A_1 \cap A_2)^c) = P(A_1^c \cup A_2^c)<= P (A_1)^c + P(A_2)^c $$

My question is: Which part in the venn diagram is this part is depicted at? $$P(A_1^c \cup A_2^c)$$ I tried to visualize it but as far as I understand $P(A_1^c)$ simply means ALL area that is not $P(A_1)$, which means all areas including the areas outside the circles, as long as it's still in the sample space.

Can anybody help clarify my misunderstanding here? Thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In this diagram,

- $A_1^c$ is the orange and red areas outside $A_1$
- $A_2^c$ is the pink and red areas  outside $A_2$
- $A_1^c \cup A_2^c$ is the pink, orange and red areas, the union of the previous areas

[image: Venn]

Comment: Thanks Henry! This is very clear. One question though, so if `Ac1∪Ac2` is the pink, orange, and red area, then how can I depict the pink and orange only? `(A1∪A2)^c`?

Comment: @speedy_catch - Pink and orange is $A \text{ XOR } B$, the symmetric difference.  Some people write this as $A \triangle B$ or $A \oplus B$ though you could use $(A \cap B^c) \cup (A^c \cap B)$ to be clear

Comment: Thanks Henry! You've been super helpful!